# Number of subsets of particular type

Tags: combinatorics

Let $X$ be a set with $2m+1$ elements, where $m\ge 4$. What is the number of subsets of $X$ having at least $(m + 1)$ elements?

I tried to do it by taking $m=4$ (in particular), but I could not get the answer.

Comment: Doing a particular case is a good way to start, if nothing more general in the way of an approach occurs to you.  Explaining how far you got with $m=4$ would improve your Question.  See [this introduction to posting mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) here.

Answer (score 1):

For $X$ having $2m+1$ elements (*any* $m \geq 0$) :

- What is the total number of subsets of $X$?
- Suppose $A \subset X$ has more than $m+1$ elements. See that $A^c$, the complement of $A$, has at most $m$ elements.
- Suppose that $B\subset X$ has at most $m$ elements. See that $B^c$ has at least $m+1$ elements.
- From the above, conclude that the subsets having at most $m$ elements are the same in number as those having at least $m+1$ elements.
- Since every subset is one of the types above, the number of subsets having at least $m+1$ elements is half of the total number of subsets of $X$.
- Conclude.

Comment: Hi, you can accept the answer if it is good.